# Limit of solutions of a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuously differentiable function and $\mathbf{A}$ be a constant matrix. Suppose that $\| e^{At}\|\leq 2^{-9t}$ and $\|f(x)\|\leq 5\|x\|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the differential equation $$x'=Ax+f(x),\ \ x(0)=\xi.$$ Show that if $\phi(t)=\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1(t)\\\cdots\\ \phi_n(t) \end{bmatrix}$ is a solution of the above differential equation then $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\phi_i(t)=0$, for all $i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$.

How to deal with this kind of problem? Usually, $f$ is considered to be a fucntion of $t$, but here, it's a function of $x$, which makes it difficult.

Comment: You will assume that $x=\phi(t)$ and then $f$ will become a function of a function of $t$.

Comment: $x$ is considered as an unknown here. That's the problem. We know that it is a function of $t$.

Comment: I don't see any problem.

Comment: Could you, please give me some hint on how to show that the limit of any solution is 0?

Comment: why don't you write $b(t)=f(x(t))$ and just solve the equation as you learned in class?

Comment: In fact, it is impossible to get a general solution for the above ODE. The only thing that we can show is that all solutions go to 0 as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: One first idea would be to use the integrating factor of the linear part and see how far one gets, that is, consider $y(t)=e^{-At}x(t)$ and $y'(t)=g(t,y(t))=e^{-At}f(e^{At}y(t))$ and try to apply the bounds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried and I think it works. First, the ODE  $$x'=Ax+g(t,x),\ \ x(\tau)=\xi$$ can be written as $$x=e^{(t-\tau)A}\xi+\int_\tau^te^{(t-s)A}g(s,x(s))ds.$$ In the above ODE, $g(t,x)=f(x).$ Now, taking the norm, we get that\begin{eqnarray*}
\|x\|&\leq&  \|e^{(t-\tau)A}\xi\|+\int_\tau^t\|e^{(t-s)A}f(x(s))\|ds\\
&\leq&\|e^{(t-\tau)A}\|\|\xi\|+\int_\tau^t\|e^{(t-s)A}\|\|f(x(s))\|ds\\
&\leq & 2^{-9(t-\tau)}\|\xi\|+5\int_\tau^t2^{-9(t-s)}\|x\|.ds
\end{eqnarray*}
therefore, we get that $$\|x\|2^{9(t-\tau)}\leq \|\xi\|+5\int_\tau^t2^{9(s-\tau)}\|x\|ds.$$
Use Gronwall’s inequality to get $$\|x\|2^{9(t-\tau)}\leq \|\xi\|e^{5(t-\tau)}\Rightarrow \|x\|\leq \|\xi\|2^{-4t},$$ where I used $\tau=0$. I think the result is clear, now. Please, check if I made some error.

Comment: So, the second line works also even $g$ is a function of both $x$ and $t$?

Comment: you mean, $x=e^{(t-\tau)A}\xi+\int_\tau^te^{(t-s)A}g(s,x(s))ds.$? To check that, what you have to do is just computing $x'$ and you will see.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that it works only when $g$ is a function of $t$, that's why I did not think about writing it this way.

Comment: You're welcome. As I said, what you have to do is just computing $x'$ and you will see. Also, check all the details. Maybe, I mad some errors